# Dropdown primary navigation menu not working

Tags: menus, dropdown, sub-menu

I have installed a theme on WordPress added pages, created a custom menu called Primary Nav.
I have then assigned this as my Primary Menu. I have child pages and the menu looks like this.

I have looked at the WordPress resources to find a solution but it seems as though I have followed the instructions on creating drop-down menus.

[image]

However when I go to the previewDNS site the drop down doesn't work.

The code is below, if another area is required please let me know where on the source page I will find it and I will add here.

```
    <div class="ddsmoothmenu"><ul id="menu-primary-nav" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-125" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-125"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=27">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-117" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=47">Portfolio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-119"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=41">Packages</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-120"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=103">Photography Prices</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=97">Wedding Albums</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=99">Signature Frames</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-121"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=101">Wedding Stationery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=31">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-118" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-118"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=44">FAQ&#8217;s</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116"><a href="http://hutchisonhaines.co.uk.previewdns.com/?page_id=72">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: @kaiser bit of an ironic post.

Comment: Hm? What "ironic post"?

Comment: You said nothing to add. Yet made a comment. This is called irony. Look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to say what you should do to fix it. The code you've supplied is the html output not the PHP code right?

[Take a look at one of my previous answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28501/how-to-create-a-drop-down-menu-like-in-twenty-eleven-theme/28503#28503). Make sure you use the Updated for **Edited For WordPress 3.3 Compatibility** section of the answer. If you're still unsure, maybe posting your code and add a comments so I'll know to return to the question.

Comment: Where in the code will I find this part? I will then copy and post it. Thanks.

Comment: If you have the custom menus feature you'll find register_nav_menus in your themes functions.php file. Then you will have some code in your header.php file to display the menu's. It should be easy to find. If you have custom menu's enabled it would look something like this: wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main'. If you don't have custom nav's it would probably just be like this: wp_list_pages();..

Answer (score 0):

I recently retrofitted a pre 3.0 theme using this article:

http://wpmu.org/how-to-add-navigation-menus-to-your-wordpress-theme/

It worked for me where many other articles failed.

It shows code that should be added. Where to put it. What CSS to use.