# Adding Sub Menu In a theme which Do not have Menu Options

Tags: menus, theme-options, sub-menu

I am a new bee in wordpress but i can code in PHP. I have a free wordpress theme installed on my local host. The theme Do not have an option to add to add menu/sub menu in it. It comes with predefined number of menus.
What i want is , can i add sub menu in the theme using some php skills? what i want is, a drop down sub menu when we hover over a menu..

Can i do it? if yes, How can i do it? i searched a lot, got videos and help about sub menus, but all of the help is about the themes which allow sub menu.

**Clarification :-**

i am not an expert, but what i know and what i think is that, it is a wordpress issue, i would need to code in menu.php or function.php to append sub menu to each element of main menu. The theme does not allow sub menu. I need  sub menu be created in theme.

i am using Wordpress Christmas theme 1.1 (free) by [instantshift](http://www.instantshift.com/)

Comment: can you clarify how this is a wordpress question, and not a CSS question?

Comment: yes. it is wordpress question. I want to add sub menus in main menu..

Comment: I'm aware that you think it is a wordpress question, I am asking you to clarify on just HOW it is a wordpress question, and not a CSS question...or even a user support question for your theme really. Preferably make this clarification in the question.

Comment: Maybe I can help clarify for N e w B e e. It's a WordPress question because he didn't have the WP Nav menu function. If the theme had custom navigation enabled then it would have simply been a CSS question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here:
[Dropdown Like Twenty-Eleven Theme Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28501/how-to-create-a-drop-down-menu-like-in-twenty-eleven-theme/28503#28503)

Be sure to use the updated code toward the bottom of my answer. It should be self explanatory, but if you have any issues let me know and I'll help you out. Be sure to back up your files before changing them in case you break it.

**How to Add the Menu After The Code is in Place**
Once the menu is installed you should notice that the custom menu's are now available in Appearance>Menu's. Just type a menu name in the box provided, add some pages and posts, then drag the sub-menu pages below and to the right of the parent menu item and release. Be sure to save the menu when you're finished.

Comment: nice answer man...how can i get you on chat? or mail? just need to make the learning ..nothing else

Comment: Do you have enough points to join the chat room?

Comment: You can go to my profile page, then click my website link to contact me.

Comment: If the answer helped you the procedure is to accept the answer by clicking the check-mark. If it was a good answer you can up-vote. If it didn't work just regard this comment.