# Custom Menu in Admin doesn't change menu in browser

Tags: functions, menus

i've just begun participating these stack overflow forums yesterday and had a great experience with someone who could problem solve with me. working from the admin panel under the themes tab i have what looks like a working theme locations panel. i followed instructions i found for installing the proper php code in the proper functions.php file and then placed it where i wanted it to appear in the proper file for my theme. my issue is it won't actually function the way it was intended, i have 3 different menu's created but the site displays every page i created. i obviously slipped somewhere along the way but i can't find where.

here's what i have in my functions.php:

```
        add_theme_support( 'menus' );

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
function my_custom_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
            'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
        )
    );
}
```

here's whats in my sidebar.php:

```
<aside>
    <div class="textBody">
    <div class="sideNav">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'extra-menu' ) ); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

still learning, even posting on this site has a learning curve...
thanks for reading this and any help or time is appreciated.

Comment: Please use proper Upper-/lowercase letters. That makes a much better reading experience. Thanks.

Comment: @Ijan Hilaire Have you set menus in Appearance->menu in admin page?

Answer (score 1):

Your menu name doesn't match in your sidebar. The `theme_location` should match the name of one of the registered menu's in your functions.php file.

Try replacing what you have with this:

**For the** `functions.php` **file:**

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
function my_custom_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary' => __( 'primary' ),
      'secondary' => __( 'secondary' )
      )
    );
  }
?>
```

**For the** `sidebar.php` **file:**

```
<aside>
  <div class="textBody">
    <div class="sideNav">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: hi jared, thanks for catching that the name didn't match. i've been trying to switch through the code to see what works and didn't return the names to a matching state. that said, the code you passed me still didn't unlock this side navigation.

Comment: Depending on your version of WordPress it might need to be placed inside of a `after_theme_setup` function/hook. See my answer to this question (the section labeled ["the FIX"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28503/5339) is what you should read). Let me know if that doesn't work or if you need more help.

Comment: hey jared, i'm sorry its taken days for me to respond but i had to abandon my original design and hope by modifying an existing theme i can satisfy my client. i'll back to revisit this issue as soon as i get this current project delivered or find time to finish resolving this issue.